# free variables in nested function in python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

What exactly are `free variables` in `nested functions` scenario in python. Would anyone please explain in detail what they are useful for and how they are differ from normal variables?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29 & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
def outer(outer_param):
    # `outer` has no free variables
    outer_var = 2

    def inner(inner_param):
        # `outer_param` and `outer_var` are free variables of `inner`
        inner_var = outer_param + outer_var + inner_param
        return inner_var
```